# PHP Associative array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to add keys to each of these two arrays so that I can access all the data as one array. Here is what I have. Tried multiple posts on Stack Overflow but so far nothing has concreted this concept for me:

```
$result = array(); 
$age_men = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
$age_women = array("Sally"=>"32", "Debra"=>"30", "Miranda"=>"40");

$result += ["Men" => $age_men];
$result += ["Women" => $age_women];

print_r($result);

//desired output
Array
(
    [Men] => Array
        (
            [Peter] => 35
            [Ben] => 37
            [Joe] => 43         
        )

    [Women] => Array
        (
            [Sally] => 32
            [Debra] => 30
            [Miranda] => 40

        )
)
```

Comment: $result["Men"] = $age_men;  $result["Women"] = $age_women;

Comment: And what is the problem? Your code gives you exactly what you want: https://3v4l.org/5U4Ok

Comment: your code also working then what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working and another way is

```
$result["Men"] = $age_men; $result["Women"] = $age_women;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$result["Men"]  = $age_men;
$result["Women"]= $age_women;
```